# Duplicating rows within cell footer view of tableView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I have two Xib's in tableview, One is cell custom UITableViewCell Xib and second is UIView custom view xib (which is `footerView`). On clicking date cell it shows me appointment list. (image attached for reference).
I am getting data from `SQLite` and then records append to model.

- Issue is for unknown reason it duplicates the appointment list in `footerView`. First when it load data its fine. When I move/scorll tableView or come back to same page it shows duplicate.
- I used `for loop` displaying appointment list record in footerView. (in **cellForRowAt**)
- I have checked but there is **no duplicate data append in array** model `var downloadAppData: [DownloadDisplay] = []`

> How to avoid duplicating footer view rows in cell TableView?

deceleration:
`var downloadAppData: [DownloadDisplay] = []`

Model:

```
struct DownloadDisplay : Codable {
    var date: Int64?
    var appointments: [Appointment]?
    var progress: Double?
    var isFinished: Bool?
}

struct Appointment : Codable {

    let appointmentHour : String?
    let backgroundColorDark : String?
    let backgroundColorLight : String?
    let controlHour : String?
    let date : String?
    let id : Int?
    let isProjectManual : Bool?
    let projectDistrict : String?
    let projectFirmName : String?
    let projectName : String?
    let projectType : String?
    let subTitle : String?
    let warmingType : String?
}
```

TableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return downloadAppData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DownloadEntryViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DownloadEntryViewCell
        let dic = downloadAppData[indexPath.row]
        let content = datasource[indexPath.row]


        let appDate = Date(milliseconds: dic.date ?? 0)        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "tr_TR_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy EEEE"
        let convertDate = dateFormatter.string(from: appDate)

        cell.fileNameLabel.text = "\(convertDate)" + " Randevuları"

        var stackHeight:CGFloat = 0.0

        // footer view xib. 
        for i in (dic.appointments)! {
            let child_view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FooterView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FooterView
            child_view.projName.text = "\(i.projectName ?? "")" + "  " + "\(i.subTitle ?? "")"
            cell.stackViewFooter.addArrangedSubview(child_view)
            stackHeight = stackHeight + 33.0
        }


        if content.expanded == false {

            cell.rightView.backgroundColor = ("#556f7b").toColor()
            cell.fileNameLabel.textColor = ("#eceff1").toColor()
            cell.progressLabel.textColor = ("#eceff1").toColor()
            cell.individualProgress.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 69, width: 360, height: 2)
            cell.individualProgress.progress = 0
            cell.individualProgress.backgroundColor = ("#cfd8dc").toColor()

       }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cells are **reused**. That means anything you do to a cell will still be in effect when that cell is reused.

In your case, you are adding (more) subviews to a stackView each time `cellForRowAt` is called.

You could either:

**A)** edit your cell class and implement `prepareForReuse()`, where you would remove any existing subviews from the stackView

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.stackViewFooter.subviews.forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

or

**B)** remove the subviews before adding new ones in `cellForRowAt`

```
    // first
    cell.stackViewFooter.subviews.forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // then
    for i in (dic.appointments)! {
        ...
        cell.stackViewFooter.addArrangedSubview(child_view)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I have implemented with success. Perfect solution. 
One more thing after using `footerView` why I am not getting space between cells? I can add one more image  any idea?

Comment: @Newbie - if the cell has no added subviews, `stackViewFooter` will have a height of Zero. I'm assuming `stackViewFooter` is constrained to the bottom of the cell's `contentView`? If so, and you want some empty space at the bottom, change the `.constant` for that bottom constraint.

Comment: let me fix it and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the subview just check that it has already been added or not, because cellForRow gets called every-time you scroll the tableView. You can do this by giving a viewTag to the subview or by maintaining a bool value in model class.

Comment: Can you give example for this please?, I am struggling hard for this thing